# Fallo a pasar test setter en String

Tags: java

En el siguiente código no se que me falla en los setter y getter, me estoy volviendo loco. Le tengo que pasar el siguiente test y me da error en la salida a mostrar el error.

test-->

```
void testSetName() {
   employee.setName("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur vestibulum.");
   assertEquals("[ERROR] Employee's name cannot be longer than 50 characters", outContent.toString().replaceAll("\n|\r\n", System.getProperty("line.separator").trim()));
}
```

---

```
package es.casa.pruebaSetter;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Employee {

    private int id = 0;
    static private int nextId;

    private String name;

    //contructor por defecto
    public Employee() {

        id = 12;
        name = "Lorem Ipsum";

    }

    //constructor

    public Employee(String name) {
        setId();
        incNextId();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    private void setId() {
        this.id = getNextId();
    }

    public static int getNextId() {
        return nextId;
    }

    private void incNextId() {
        nextId += 1;
    }

    public String getName() {
        if (name.length() > 50) {
            System.out.println("[ERROR] Employee's name cannot be longer than 50 characters");
        }
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

}
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y menciona cuál es el error que tienes.

Answer (score 0):

De entrada, la cadena "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur vestibulum." tiene 51 caracteres... Y según tu getter, debe imprimir en pantalla el error...
Por otro lado, ¿Por qué la validación está en el getter y no en el setter?
No entiendo muy bien tu problema, pero me parece que va algo como:

```
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    if( name.length()>50 ){
        System.out.println("[Error]: Employee's name cannot be longer than 50 characters");
    } else {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

En el getter, simplemente se devuelve el valor porque ahí no hay condiciones. En el caso del setter, ahí es donde validas que la longitud de la cadena sea mayor a 50, en cuyo caso imprimes el mensaje de error. En caso contrario, se acepta y se asigna...

Comment: Gracias, lo puse mal aquí, lo tenía en el setter y si estaba correcto, el problema lo tenía con el JUnit que me daba error siempre.

Answer (score 0):

Hola para hacer test deberías tener un método especializado y hacer el test sobre este método y no sobre la entidad

```
public static void validarNombre(String name){
    if (name.length()>50) {
        System.out.println("Error la cadena tiene " + name.length());
    }else {
        employee.setName=name;
    }
}
```

y lo llamarías  `validarNombre("xsdvfgngfdxsdvfgngfdxsdvfgngfdxsdvfgngfdxsdvfgngfd1");` esto debería devolver una String de error o añadirlo, espero haberte ayudado.